# Looking for a verb that describes a sort of "despondent lounging" that might occur when one is depressed, in emotional pain

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

I do it sometimes. I associate it with a deep, painful feeling of despair, depression, etc... i feel like I've seen it in a lot of paintings and sculptures. This image sort of depicts it, I was thinking more of a "fanned out over a fainting chair with a wrist held to the forehead with hand frail" sort of pose, but I'm sure that the word in question would cover all kinds of sad-looking poses.

This is my first post by the way, I'm a long-time lurker and a big fan of the community :)

Comment: Ruminating maybe?

Comment: Congrats on your first post! IMHO lurkers make the best participants because lurkers already understand how it all works. Heck, I lurked around here for 6 years before I took the plunge. ;-) // Are you looking for **verbs** only, i.e., you do _not_ want nouns or adjectives? Relatedly, _how/where/for what audience_ do you wish to use this word--what is the context? Thanks!

Comment: One reason I'm asking for more specificity is that I can provide a (hopefully) good answer (nouns, adjectives) for "deep, painful feeling of despair, depression, etc.", but I don't want to write up an answer that you are not seeking.

Answer (score 3):

You're [*moping*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mope) when you're lounging or wandering "listlessly and aimlessly because of unhappiness or boredom."

Comment: +1 Moping or _moping about_ could definitely work, particularly if you want to convey a sense similar to pouting, i.e., the [2nd sense of the word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mope) in the _American Heritage Roget's Thesaurus_: "To keep aloof from others in moody silence; to indulge in sullen ill-humour; to be sulky."

Answer (score 2):

Does languish work?

From Merriam-Webster,

1. To continue for a long time without activity or progress in an unpleasant or unwanted situation
2. To be or live in a state of depression or decreasing vitality

Comment: +1 I like _languish_ because historically it meant "To droop in spirits; to pine or brood, esp. with love or grief" which corresponds with the visual image OP described (the image does not show for me). [definition from OED Online.]

Comment: And [languor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/languor) the noun for the corresponding state.

Answer (score 0):

Lolling, lolling around. To loll.

It means lying around, lazing around aimlessly, not doing anything, floppy.

Definition:

to lie, sit, or hang down in a relaxed, informal, or uncontrolled way:
I spent most of the weekend lolling about/around on the beach.
The dogs tongue lolled out of its mouth.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lolling